# Jstl conditional <c:when not assigning value passed from jsp variable

Tags: jsp, jstl, conditional-statements

I need the following logic to occur:

1. Get the *shippingDate* from the db
2. If the *shippingDate* has value (not empty), display it
3. Otherwise, set the *shippingDate* that is displayed on the page to *today's date*. 
   This way the user can just submit the page and the default value (today's date) will be written to db. The user can also choose to change that value.

This is what I have so far:

myJsp.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<% String todaysDate = cm.GetMonth() + "/" + cm.GetDay() + "/" + cm.GetYear();%>
...
 <c:forEach var="i" items="${bean.results}">
     <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${empty i.shippingDate}">
             <c:set var="shippingDate" value="<%=todaysDate%>" scope="request"></c:set>
         </c:when>
     </c:choose>
 <TD>
     <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="shippingDate" id="shippingDate" value="${i.shippingDate}"/>                            
 </TD>
```

Above code works when there is value in db, but it doesn't set *shippingDate* to *today's date* if nothing is returned from db.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What result will you get on `<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="shippingDate" id="shippingDate" value="${shippingDate}"/>`? It seems you set local variable `shippingDate` whithout changing `i.shippingDate`.

Comment: @tarashypka that's true, if I set value="${shippingDate} then I get todaysDate, for the values that have something in db, I get nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another variable and assign it appropriately:

```
<c:forEach var="i" items="${bean.results}">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty i.shippingDate}">
      <c:set var="inputDate" value="<%=todaysDate%>" scope="request"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <c:set var="inputDate" value="${i.shippingDate}" scope="request"/>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
  <td>
    <input type="text" NAME="shippingDate" id="shippingDate" value="${inputDate}"/>                            
  </td>
  ...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote after you commented earlier on local variable :) thank you